# changing signal strength programmatically in android

Tags: android

I want to change the network signal strength programmatic-ally in android..Even though signal is full i want to make it 50% or even 0%. Friends is it possible..?If possible please me how to do it..Thanks in advance..

Comment: This is probably impossible, it goes against the whole concept of OS / Application separation for a start. Secondly, why would you even want to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It sounds like your trying to do something malicious.

Comment: In his defense, it could be used for testing and simulation of bad signals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, no it is not possible, the Android SDK only provides a method to get the GSM Signal Strength not set it. For more information on the `android.telephony.SignalStrength` object, check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#getGsmSignalStrength())

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to change any information related to gsm like signalstrength or MCC or MNC provided your devcie is ROOTED. Only then you can use setprop to do so .Note you cannot set using java reflection method as it reads and caches it from the native methods. You have to used NDK on rooted phone .